# pass values from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

in my html5 page there is a search textbox with a haperlink. when i click on hyperlink value does not goes to controller. i can not use form because on this page i am already using a form.

```
<input type="text" name="searchval"/>
 <a href="users" class="btn btn-sm btn-white">Go!</a>
```

and in controller

```
function user()
dim val as string = Request("searchval")
```

but searchval always return nothing even i put some text in textbox. Please help

Comment: is ur <input type="text" name="searchval"/> inside form tag?

Comment: Can you post the full code for your controller, and your view? It will help us verify if your HTML code is in a `<form>` and whether the ActionMethod looks OK.

Comment: actually problem is this that this code is written in a form. but that form's action is something else. i have to do this only writing this code

Comment: @user2875761 What do you mean? If the form's action doesn't point to your controller action then it's not going to work, is it? If you can't change the form action, you may need to use javascript to pick up your form values and make an AJAX request to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks do not submit forms. You need a `form` tag and a submit button.

```
<form action="/users" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="searchval"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

You also need to make sure your VB.NET method is routed to appropriately by the form action and is actually a controller action:

```
Function User() As ActionResult
```

Comment: Function user() As ActionResult                                            Dim name1 As String = Request.Form("searchval")   this is my controller

Comment: You need a submit button, not a hyperlink. You also need to check your routing. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

Comment: Thanks. its working with form. i was trying to do it without form. because this code was written in another form. Now i wrote it in a form outside the other form.

Answer (score 0):

when you click on hyperlink call ajax function.

function Searchfunction() {
        var searchValue = $("#searchval").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            data: { "searchval": searchValue },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#dvSearch').html(result);
            }
        });

    }